# Is NUL set automatically, if I provide an extra element for it in the declaration of the respective char array?

Tags: c++, c, string, initialization, nul

Is `'\0'` set automatically if I provide an extra element for it, but left it in the initialization string?

Like:

```
char a[6] = {"Hello"};   // <- Is NUL set here automatically?
```

---

I´ve did one experiment with C and C++:`

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char NEWYEAR[16] = {"Happy New Year!"};
    printf("%s\n",NEWYEAR);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Happy New Year!
```

---

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char NEWYEAR[16] = {"Happy New Year!"};
    std::cout << NEWYEAR << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Happy New Year!
```

---

The compilers did not threw an error or warning and the result is as desired. So it might seem to work correctly. But is that really true?

- Is everything correct by doing so?
- Is this maybe bad programming style?
- Does this cause any issues?

Comment: This is an area where C and C++ differs, so please pick *one* language.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tested it with both. The result seems to be equivalent.

Comment: "*Is this maybe bad programming style*" if you do not rely on the array having a specific size it's much saver to just do `char a[] = "Hello";`. The compiler will select the size to fit, including the `0`-terminator. The curly braces are not needed , BTW.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica It "works" because you test only with code that happens to be valid in both languages. C and C++, while sharing common roots and some syntax, really are two different languages with different rules and semantics.

Comment: But it is equally useful to understand that the curly braces are *allowed*, because without braces you cannot do a compound literal in C...

Comment: *"`NEWYEAR[16]`"* More suitable with the current date to have `NEWYEAR[20]` ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, I understand that. But where especially is the difference? Is this valid in C, but not in C++? The output results *seem* to work.

Comment: There are *vast* numbers of things that *may* work in certain situations in both C and C++. That doesn't make them a good idea since they may stop working in a different implementation or even next Tuesday :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo So what I understand as conclusion is: As opposed to C, In C++, to incorporate a dedicated element for `\0` without initializing it, isn´t a good thing to do because the result is implementation-defined?

Comment: RobertS: That is not the difference between C and C++ here. The difference is that C allows you to write `char foo[3] = "foo";` and C++ does not. The C standard says "Successive bytes of the string literal including the terminating null character if there is room ..." (6.7.9/14), while C++ insists that "There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements." (11.6.2/2 with a clear example). Both of them consider the trailing `\0` to be part of the string literal, so it is guaranteed to be used as an initialization value (in the case of C, if there is room).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more complex than that

```
char a[6] = "Hello";
```

will initialize the array of characters to `Hello\0`, because `Hello` has an implicit terminating zero.

```
char a[6] = "Hello\0";
```

would be valid in C, but invalid in C++ because the literal is *7* characters long, having both an implicit terminator and explicit embedded null character. C allows the literal to drop the *implicit* terminator. [C11 6.7.9p14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14):

> 14. An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the elements of the array.

```
char a[5] = "Hello";
```

would be valid C, resulting in a char array that does *not* contain a zero-terminated string. It is invalid in C++.

(emphasis mine). It means that the implicit terminating null is optionally added, if there is room in the array, but it does not need to.

And

```
char a[4] = "Hello";
```

in C would bring the literal Hell, because while it is a **constraint violation** in C ([C11 6.7.9p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p2)),

> 2. No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

attempting to initialize more elements than there are items in a list usually just generates a *warning* in many compilers and is then often ignored by programmers. The paragraph 14 does not have an exception for anything other besides the implicit terminator.

And lastly

```
char a[7] = "Hello";
```

in both C and C++ would result in a character array of *7* elements containing the characters `Hello\0\0`, because in an array having an initializer, the elements not explicitly *initialized* by the initializer will be default-initialized as if initialized by literal `0`. In this case the first 6 elements will be initialized explicitly and the 7th implicitly.

---

Given the possibility of silently truncating the terminator in C, it is better to just omit the array size and write

```
char a[] = "Hello";
```

This will declare `a` as array of 6 elements, just like `char a[6] = "Hello";`, but you cannot mistype the array size.

Comment: That is exactly what I have searching for, to express possibilities and the differences between C and C++ in that case. I have 2 questions left: 1. You said `char a[6] = "Hello\0";` and `char a[5] = "Hello";`are invalid in C++. How may I declare then an char array in C++? Should I only do it like `char a[] = "Hello";` or is it allowed to initialize the characters separately with NUL as well like: char a[6] = `H`,`e`,`l`,`l`,`o`,`\0`;` 2. Shall I *always* do it like `char a[] = "Hello";? Do you code in this way only?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica I choose the option 3: "I don't do no C++".

Comment: @AntiiHaapala :-) Ok, I understand. But back to what is valid and what not: Can I do  char a[6] = `H`,`e`,`l`,`l`,`o`,`\0`; in C++ or is there anything wrong about it?

Comment: @Roberts: `char a[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0};` is valid in both C and C++. The braces and apostrophes are obligatory. You can (in both languages) use `'\0'` instead of 0 if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

If there's space for the null-terminator then it will be added.

In C (but not C++) if the size of the array is the length of the string except the null-terminator, then the null-terminator will not be added. So e.g.

```
char a[5] = "Hello";
```

is valid, but there won't be a null-terminator in the array.

It's not valid to provide a smaller size than the string length.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't *sure* about that last sentence, I thought it might just truncate. But you're right, C11 has the constraint: "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity".